# VMware Toolbar does not open

Tags: windows-7, vmware, toolbar, vmware-workstation

I know, usually people want to get rid of it, but I actually find it quite useful. But since yesterday it won't open any more, when I'm in fullscreen mode. I still can see the small bit on top of the screen, but it does not react to my mouse.

At the time I noticed that it does no longer work, I also had a remote desktop session open in my host (Win 7). So, I assumed it was some overlay effect and only one of both toolbars is working. But today the VMware toolbar is still gone, although I rebooted the host (and the VM - but the effect can also be seen, when no VM is running).

I already tried deleting my settings and config files but with no success. Any ideas what might cause the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to Workstation 11 last week and started having this same issue almost immediately, though I hadn't identified the cause. I've been running Workstation 10 for about 18 months and don't ever recall this issue before.

The only workaround I've found so far (which isn't exactly convenient!) is to pause / close all running VMs and then reboot the host (I'm running on W8.1 with W7, Vista and XP guests and all are fully up to date with Windows updates and have the latest VM Tools installed).

This is the first post I've found that reports the exact issue so I'm guessing that this may be the result of a recent Windows update - hopefully a quick fix can be found.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem with Workstation 14 and it appears that applications with overlays can cause this. In my case it was Steam.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The quick workaround if you want the toolbar back would be to exit full screen mode (Ctrl+Alt+Enter) and the go back to full screen mode. The toolbar started to show up fixing the issue (until it happened again!)